# Show that $\int^1_0 \mathrm{d}x \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{3}\frac{\Gamma(7/4)}{\Gamma(5/4)}$

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function

I came across the following integral identity
$$I = \int^1_0 \mathrm{d}x \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{3}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$
involving the gamma function, but I cannot seem to derive the result myself.

My take is to expand the denominator and do term-by-term integration:
$$ 
\begin{align}
I &= \int^1_0 \mathrm{d}x \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}} \\ &= \int^1_0 \mathrm{d}x \text{ }x^2\left(1-x^4\right)^{-1/2} \\
&= \int^1_0 \mathrm{d}x \sum^\infty_{n=0}\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}(-1)^n x^{4n+2}. \\
\end{align}
$$
Here we can exchange the sum and the integral to get
$$ 
\begin{align}
I &= \sum^\infty_{n=0}\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}(-1)^n\int^1_0 \mathrm{d}x\text{ }x^{4n+2} \\ &= \sum^\infty_{n=0}\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{4n+3} \\ &= \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{4n+3}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n n!}, 
\end{align}
$$
where we define $(-1)!!$ to be $1$. I think this method reaches a dead end, since showing that this expansion is equivalent to the desired expression feels just as cumbersome as the original problem.

Comment: Hint: rewrite the integral as a [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution $$x = u^{1/4}, \quad dx = \frac{1}{4} u^{-3/4} \, du,$$
immediately gives
$$\int_{x=0}^1 x^2 (1-x^4)^{-1/2} \, dx = \frac{1}{4} \int_{u=0}^1 u^{-1/4} (1-u)^{-1/2} \, du.$$  Now apply the beta function identity
$$\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)} = \int_{x=0}^1 x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \, dx$$ and also recall that $$\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}.$$